# -[UITableView reloadData] shows changes only after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5.1

I update the `UITableView` on timer. I change data in array, then call `-[UITableView reloadData]`. But nothing is changed until I scroll the table or switch tabs in the tab bar. What's happening? How can I avoid this?

Comment: do you call reloadData on main thead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reload table on not main thread

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in that:

```objective-c
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    self.newList = [self loadData];
    [self.delegate list:self didUpdate:self.newList];
});
```

Delegate call was on the background thread. If you want to update UI you should do in on the main thread.

```objective-c
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    self.newList = [self loadData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.delegate list:self didUpdate:self.newList];
    });
});
```